# Python for loop to find a character and add substrings before/after that character

Tags: python

I am new to programming and am trying to work through computer science circles by the University of Waterloo and am stuck on this exercise: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltVu9.png
The code in the image is what I have come up with so far.

The exercise wants me to take the substrings from before and after the "+" character and add them together using a for loop and I can't figure out how to get the substring. So far I've tried

```
print(S[0:len(char)])
```

Comment: Think about what that statement is doing. You are just going to be printing out the first character of the string each time because the length of `char` is 1. Also please put your whole code in the question instead of linking to an image.

Comment: Did you already hear of `str.split()`? Or are you told to do this manually by using a loop over all characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the substring of the characters before and after the '+' symbol, you need to get the characters before the current position of the '+' char and after.

```
S = '12+5'
for pos in range(len(S)):
    char = S[pos]
    if char == '+':
        sub_1 = S[:pos] # Get string before pos
        sub_2 = S[pos + 1:] # Get string after pos
        print('{} + {}'.format(sub_1, sub_2))

# Output: 12 + 5
```

However, if you are just wanting the simplest solution without thinking of how to do it manually then as others have said using `.split()` makes things easy. Since `.split()` will split a string into a list of strings separated by a specific character.

Using `.split()` the code can become like this:

```
S = '12+5'
split_S = S.split('+')  # Creates a list of ['12', '5']
# Make sure our list has 2 items in it to print
if len(split_S) == 2:
    print('{} + {}'.format(split_S[0], split_s[1])

# Output: 12 + 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this:

```
nums = S.split('+')
print(int(nums[0])+int(nums[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum([int(c) for c in input().split('+')])

5+12
Out: 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Epicdaface25 is right, you could simply use

```
nums = S.split('+')
print(int(nums[0])+int(nums[1]))
```

But if you need to use a `for` loop, Karl's answer is the better option. However, you would not

```
print('{} + {}'.format(sub_1, sub_2))
```

you would need to print `int(sub_1) + int(sub_2)` to have Python actually add the two numbers and display the sum, as opposed to the mathematical expression.